# Dynamically applying formatting to regular expressions

Tags: automation, l3regex

One useful tool I find in InDesign are the Grep styles. With them, one can define character styles (e.g., boldface in small caps) for whatever expression matches the grep pattern.

I know this is quite easy to *statically* carry this out with the help of most modern text editors — viz., searching for a regex pattern and replacing all matches with the desired code (e.g., `{\bfseries\scshape. . .}` or whatever).

But can this be done *dynamically* in LaTeX?

For instance, I would like to tell LaTeX something like the following:

```
\newregexstyle{^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$}{\bfseries\scshape}
```

so that all matching expressions (in this case, syntactically valid email addresses) are dynamically formatted in the desired manner. (Yes, I know — there would be a problem here with chars `%`, `@`, `$` and the like. But this is just an example. The syntax should conform to `l3regex`'s rules.)

The good thing about dynamically sorting this out is (1) that the coded text looks cleaner (and easier to edit), (2) that when writing the text I should care not for these expressions' styles, and (3) that I can easily change (or even remove) the format at any time without much editing. (I'm thinking here of complex documents with many `\include` and `\input` commands.)

Comment: I don't agree with your assertion (1): `\email{x@y.z}` is the way to go in TeX and what makes for cleaner code.

Comment: `x@y.z` seems to me cleaner than `\email{x@y.z}`, just as `\email{...}` does in comparison with `{\bfseries\scshape...}`. Be that as it may, I think my question is still worth considering.

Comment: Consider also that the email address can be produced by a macro. A (La)TeX document is not only text, but also mark up.

Comment: PS. I'm thinking in cleanliness not just as a coder, but also as a (copy)editor who works with LaTeX. When copyediting text, it's easier for me to concentrate on the text and leave aside (some of) the formatting.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. That means that macros should (might) be expanded before regex styles could be applied.

Comment: It doesn't work that way.

Comment: *What* doesn't work that way?

Comment: There is *no* way to turn a mildly complex LaTeX document into something processable in the way you would like.

Comment: Why? Is it really impossible (leaving aside the question of macro expansion)?